# Есть ли в стандартной библиотеке Haskell тип, реализующий следующую идею:

Tags: рекурсия, типы-данных, haskell, контейнеры, containers

```
data Index k = EmptyIndex | PrimIndex k (Index k) | FullIndex (Index k) (Index k) deriving (Show)

{-
*Main> let ind1 = PrimIndex 3 EmptyIndex
*Main> ind1
PrimIndex 3 EmptyIndex
*Main> let ind2 = PrimIndex 4 ind1
*Main> ind2
PrimIndex 4 (PrimIndex 3 EmptyIndex)
*Main> let ind3 = FullIndex ind1 ind2
*Main> ind3
FullIndex (PrimIndex 3 EmptyIndex) (PrimIndex 4 (PrimIndex 3 EmptyIndex))
-}
```

То есть, идея в том, чтобы контейнером одного типа мог бы быть либо пустой контейнер, либо контейнер примитивов, либо контейнер контейнеров рекурсивно. (Чтобы не велосипедить)

(Возможно, название `Index` не очень удачное здесь, но смысл кода, думаю, понятен)

Чтобы два раза не задавать, задам тут же связанный вопрос, на который, почти уверен, ответом будет "нет". Можно ли использовать для кастомного контейнера (наподобие этого ↑) скобки "экзотической формы" в том смысле, как используются `[]` для стандартных списков?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип который вы описываете называется дерево. В стандартной библиотеке он есть, но выглядит не так как у вас.

На второй вопрос можно ответить положительно если вы используете компилятор `nhc98`.

Выглядеть это будет примерно так.

```
type YourType = ...
type Builder a = ..

start :: a -> Builder a
($$) :: Builder a -> a -> Builder a
end :: Builder a -> YourType

prefix start 6 +$
infix 6 $$
postfix end 6 $+
```

после этого можно будет писать `+$ 1 $$ 2 $$ 3 $+ :: YourType`.

К сожалению `[`, `,` и `]` перегрузить нельзя.

В паттерн матчинге это работать тоже не будет.